# Why does incorrectly using <> in an if in bash statement create a file?

Tags: bash, if-statement

I mistakenly used the `<>` not equal comparison to check two variables:

```
if [ "2.57" <> "5" ]
then
  echo "Banana"
fi
```

This is wrong, as I now know (`-ne` is used not `<>`).

But my question is why did it create an empty file called `5` (the second comparator)? I know that `echo Hello > file` will create it, but there is no echo here.

What causes this to happen?

Comment: Have you tried to type just this? `> 5` there's no `echo` and the file is still created…

Comment: Bash way of doing what? of truncating a file? it's not specific to Bash, it works in any POSIX shell.

Comment: By truncating I mean open with the `O_TRUNC` flag: so if the file doesn't exist, then it is created, but if it already exists, it is truncated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[` is a command, not syntax; it's a synonym for `test`. As such, `<>` is not actually an argument, but a redirection operator. You command is equivalent to

```
if test "2.56" <> "5"
then
```

with means open a file (for reading and writing) named "5" to use as standard input for `test`. `test` doesn't actually read from its standard input, so the file is essentially ignored, but the shell still opens it (and creates if if necessary) before running `test`.

---

Since `[` is a command and `<>` is a redirection operator, it is also equivalent to

```
if [ "2.57" ] <> "5"
```

Redirection operators are normally placed after all arguments, but for a simple command it can appear anywhere in the command line, even before the command itself. The following are also equivalent to your command.

```
if <> "5" [ "2.57" ]; then
if [ <> "5" "2.57" ]; then
```

( "]" is required to be the final argument with `"["`, to further the illusion of syntax.)

Comment: Nice, thanks for taking the time to explain to a newbie!